# reading csv with date and making line graphs from it

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, matplotlib

I have below data saved as `stockdata.csv`.

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
03-10-16,774.25,776.065002,769.5,772.559998
04-10-16,776.030029,778.710022,772.890015,776.429993
05-10-16,779.309998,782.070007,775.650024,776.469971
06-10-16,779,780.47998,775.539978,776.859985
07-10-16,779.659973,779.659973,770.75,775.080017
```

I have 2 questions:

1. wish to make a line chart with Date on x-axis & other 4 variables on y-axis.
   I'm getting a problem separating the date from the data to get the desired result.

   Here's my code:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
       df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\stockdata.csv',parse_dates=True,index_col=0,header=0)
   ```

   This gives me below output:

   ```
   Empty DataFrame
   Columns: []
   Index: [03-10-16,774.25,776.065002,769.5,772.559998, 04-10-16,776.030029,778.710022,772.890015,776.429993, 05-10-16,779.309998,782.070007,775.650024,776.469971, 06-10-16,779,780.47998,775.539978,776.859985, 07-10-16,779.659973,779.659973,770.75,775.080017]
   ```
2. While doing `pd.read_csv`, I've seen all codes directly key in the filepath.
   But if I exclude the **`r`** prefix, it gives an error as below:

   `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

   How do I write code without mentioning the 'read' mode ?

**Edit1:**

The problem was with my understanding of .csv. I was creating a .csv & putting data including commas there. I discovered that a .csv will appear without commas in excel csv file format, but commas appear when same file is opened in notepad.

My final code yet is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\stockdata.csv",header=0,index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])
df.plot(y=['Open','High','Low','Close']) 
plt.show()
```

This treats date in yyyy-mm-dd format and plots 10 dates instead of the input 5.
Looking to experiment with `datetime` library to correct this.

**Edit 2:**
Tweaked code to get only the 5 dates I've data for. Current code looks like this-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv("stocks.csv",header=0,index_col=0)
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%d-%m-%y")
```

It produces a graph as below:

[image: line chart]

Now the issue is, as you can see on the `x-axis`, only the first date is in correct format. I need to get all the dates in correct format.

Also, the legend comes toward top-left by default - any way to move it around, like toward top-right ?

Comment: FYI, the "r" prefix doesn't mean "read" mode—it means the backslashes in the following string aren't escape characters.

Comment: Oh thanks. That soothes the second question.

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't just "sooth" it, it completely eliminates it—so I suggest that you [edit] your question and remove that part completely. Regardless, to address the main topic of your question, you're going to need to use one of the graphing/plotting libraries available to do this sort of thing. One commonly-used one is [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org). It's documented and there are lots of related questions here already about its use.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share how do I write the filepath without mentioning 'r' ? Regarding the main question, I have been plotting graphs using matplotlib.pyplot. Point is how do I segregate the data such that Python treats Date as date & others as data.  If data is entered as separate lists, I can solve this problem. But this format & reading csv is causing issues, I guess. I am using Spyder(Python 3.7)

Comment: Sure, just escape the escape character with itself: i.e. `'C:\\Users\\stockdata.csv'`. As for how to use matplotlib to do this, I'm afraid I can't help you—so I suggest you give it a try and if you can't figure it out or get stuck, _then_ ask more specific question here. Be sure to tag your question with "matplotlib".

Comment: Thanks @martineau, it helped! I also got around the problem, although not completely. I'm updating the question I asked.